# Table view inside view, inside viewcontroller. Best way to do it?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, view, uiviewcontroller

I have a main home screen in my app which I am eventually hoping to contain a table view in the centre. When a button is pressed, the table view flips to a map view.

I would do this as part of the main view, but I want the surrounding area to stay the same. I have dragged a view into the centre of the homepage view controller, and have set up my table view there. How do I access the data in this view?

As far as I'm aware, there is no way of setting a tableviewcontroller to it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make whatever View Controller is in charge of the views conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols in your header (.h) file:

`@interface YourViewControllerClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

And then implement the appropriate methods in your implementation (.m) file.

If you're using IB, drag the TableView's datasource and delegate outlets to your view controller subclass.

Comment: Thanks, do I connect it to the viewcontroller or the First Responder? Because when I connect it to the ViewController, I get the error:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'` When I have included the method from the old TableViewController (I had the table in a separate tab at first).

Comment: Silly me, forgot to set a Reuse Identifier. Thanks!